# What's the difference between access network state (ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) and WIFI state (ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) permissions?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

In Permissions tab of Android Manifest, in the drop down there are options called `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`. What is the difference between them? Is `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` more generalized than `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) is needed for accessing [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) (mainly for monitoring network connections in general), while [`android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) grants access to [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) (for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity in particular).

Comment: So if I use ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, and check connectivity: if on WiFi will it return online or offline? Do I need to check both?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html for a useful function (isOnline) that tells whether there is an internet connection at all.

Comment: ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE can be used to check the general network state (i.e. connecting, connected) even if it's Wifi by using the ConnectivityManager's `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method.

Answer (score 5):

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` is required to check if you are connected to a network, it does not matter of what type it is (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.).

`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` is not required to prope for internet connections.

To answer most of the questions, yes you don’t need the `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` if merely checking for connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Network state refers to cellular network connectivity.

Wifi state refers to the state of the phone's Wifi connection.

Comment: Not exactly, see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html where it uses 'network status' to refer to any internet connection regardless of type.  It distinguishes between ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE and ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI.  It even gives example code for useful function (isOnline) that tells whether there is an internet connection at all.